# Is HPKP subdomain pinning relative?

Tags: http, certificate, pinning

I have a HPKP pinned domain at `sub.domain.tld` with a 2 month expiry and `includeSubdomains` flag present.

I noticed now that `sub2.domain.tld`, using a different certificate that is not pinned, still works.

Does this mean that `includeSubdomains` is *relative* to the domain sending the header, and does not cover all subdomains of `domain.tld`?

I.e. I would assume `subsub.sub.domain.tld` to fail HPKP validation with a different certificate with above configuration, but `sub2.domain.tld` to work.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is all correct. It should not be assumed that those with access to a subdomain have access to a top level domain - though the reverse can be assumed.

If it worked as you originally thought then anyone on user1.example.com could directly break user2.example.com site.

If you want to pin all subdomains then you should set your HPKP policy at the top level domain as well as at the subdomains. As most users don't typically visit the top level domain, they won't pick up this policy, so to get around this you are best to load a resource from your top level domain in your subdomain so they effectively visit your top level domain. I think this works even if that resource is redirected to your subdomain.

For example if visiting https://www.example.com you should load something like https://example.com/icon.jpg to pick up this policy from top level, even if that attempting to load that causes a redirect to https://www.example.com/icon.jpg.